# CSRF Hash is not coming in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, security, csrf

I have already set the value of `CSRF_PROTECTION` to `TRUE` in CI config.php, Also the FORM helper is already set to autoload.

I have used `form_open()` and `form_close()` in CI forms.

But my problem is that the value of `<?=$csrf['hash'];?>` is always blank. Ideally there should be some CSRF token.

Comment: Please show your view code

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `<?=$csrf['hash'];?>`?

Comment: trying to use csrf protection for forms

Comment: You don't need for that code or anything else beyond the settings you have and to use `form_open()` for CSRF protection to work. On the generated html for the page you will find `<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token_name" value="some_big_token_hash">` The `name` attribute will equal what you set in `config.php` for `$config['csrf_token_name']`

Comment: @DFriend yes everything is working fine except the value of token has is not coming

Comment: Is the CSRF cookie getting set?

Comment: No, There is no CSRF cookie

Comment: One possible reason for that is that you have `$config['cookie_secure'] = TRUE;` and are not using `https:`.

Comment: Are you getting the "'The action you have requested is not allowed." error page?

Comment: no Cookie_secure it set to FALSE and running the files on localhost so there is not SSL or HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

You need to place following array before `<?=$csrf['hash'];?>`

```
$csrf = array(
        'name' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),
        'hash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
);
```

Then it will show the hidden field with CSRF token.
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf

But if use `form_open()` and `form_close()` then it automatically generate a hidden field contain CSRF token.

Comment: There is no need for this when using `form_open()' It will automatically place a hidden input field in the form using the token and hash.

Comment: @Rejoanul Alam   Yes i am already using that array. But still no value for hash, however `<?$csrf['name'];?>` value is coming.